# uiview width is zero

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiview

I added a uigesture to my uiview using the following code

```
UIPinchGestureRecognizer *pinchRecognizer = [[UIPinchGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(scale:)];
[pinchRecognizer setDelegate:self];
[holderView addGestureRecognizer:pinchRecognizer];
[pinchRecognizer release];
```

and the code of scalling is

```
    if([(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender state] == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {

        lastScale = 1.0;
        return;
    }



    CGFloat scale = 1.0 - (lastScale - [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale]);

    CGAffineTransform currentTransform = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].transform;
    CGAffineTransform newTransform = CGAffineTransformScale(currentTransform, scale, scale);

    [[(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view] setTransform:newTransform];

    lastScale = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender scale];

    OldTransform = newTransform;

    OldCenter = [(UIPinchGestureRecognizer*)sender view].center;
```

the problem before the zooming I can get the width and height of holdview but after scaling it return zero

I use the following code to display

NSLog(@" the rectangle %f , %f ,%f, %f ", holderView.frame.origin.x, holderView.frame.origin.y, holderView.bounds.size.width , holderView.bounds.size.height ) ;

another problem is that when I add subview above it all the values return from the holderview the size the origin ,.. become zero 
any suggestion to solve that

Comment: Just fyi, `NSStringFromCGRect`.

Comment: thanks for the information , do u have a suggestion regarding the question

Answer (score 0):

Setting the transform of a view does not change the values of its frame property. So even if the frame reports back that the width is 100, it might visually be 50, or whatever, due to the transform.

The reason you get 0 for the width of your frame is probably because you either set it to 0 at some point, or haven't set it yet. You need to provide a default size to make your view visible.

Comment: I set its frame to [self.view frame]